# How to customize a dropdown list in alfresco using freemarker?

Tags: alfresco, freemarker, alfresco-share

I have the following in the model.xml

```
<constraint name="abc:values" type="LIST">
        <parameter name="allowedValues">
            <list>
                <value>Value 1</value>
                <value>Value 2</value>
                <value>Value 3</value>
                <value>Value 4</value>
                <value>Value 5</value>
                <value>Value 6</value>
            </list>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="caseSensitive"><value>true</value></parameter>
    </constraint>
```

In the share-custom.xml I have the following added so it would display the above values in a drop-down list.

```
<field-visibility>
    <show id="abc:values" />
<field-visibility>
```

I want to customize the appearance of the list by making Value 1 and Value 3 bold and display the values numbered in the format 1a, 1b, 2a, 2b, 3a,3b and so on.

I'm not very familiar with ftl and not too sure how to achieve this. Does this require using selectone ftl?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it requires one FTL.

Just make a simple FTL file with your bold text and other things & 
Call that FTL from **share-config-custom.xml** to where you are rendering that property.

> Make sure at the end of that FTL you set that value to your property

Comment: can you please give the path of the ftl file where i have to put this ftl file.